# Create new report in magento

Tags: php, magento

How do I create a new custom report in magento? I created my own, but he is seeking the wrong tempalte, continues to seek the grid.php aquivo the core, how can I tell him to get my grid.php file? This is may code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reportneworders_adminhtml_reportneworders_index>

        <adminhtml_report_statistics_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="adminhtml/report_refresh_statistics" template="tagon/report/refresh/statistics.phtml" name="myrefreshstatistics" />
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_report_statistics_index>


        <reference name="content">
            <block type="reportneworders/adminhtml_reportneworders" name="mycontainer" template="tagon/report/grid/container.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reportneworders_adminhtml_reportneworders_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Try to paste  <adminhtml_report_statistics_index> tag,  inner content in before</layout> close.
And check it.

Comment: I tried, but it did work. I believe the method getGrid() is calling the grid magento not what I created, how could I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the change does not happen because the method "get Html Grid" was looking for a setted by magento template dynamically, the change should be done in the _prepareLayout overridden method as shown below.

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true)->setTemplate('mytheme/report/grid.phtml')
    );

}
```